# Apex Component Controller can not get value from apex:inputText/inputField

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

I have a simple custom component that I want to use to send an email. The structure is like this:

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!sendEmail}" name="sendEmail" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!To}"/>
    <button type="button" onClick="sendEmail();"/>
</apex:form>
```

and a controller that is like this:

```
public with sharing class emailComponent{
    public string To { get; set; } 

    public void sendEmail(){
        system.debug(logginglevel.info,To);
    }
}
```

Now when I fire the actionFunction the correct method is called but the value of "To" will always be null. Even if I set the value in the contructor when I call the method the value will be null. I don't know if this has to do with it being a custom component controller or if there's something else im missing..

Answer (score 0):

Add "rerender" attribute to apex:actionFunction  and its should start working

Comment: ack i forgot to add it to the sample above but things are indeed being rerendered.. it seems as if the rerender is trying to process form validation or is failing validation even when values are present.